# Inanimate Objects that look good to eat

Tags: food

Is there a word for inanimate objects that look good to eat such as a cloud that looks like ice cream or cocking that looks like frosting?

Comment: A mirage? As of a pool of water in a desert. Can you supply a sentence (add it to the question) with a blank where the word you want might go?

Comment: Do you mean *caulking?*

Comment: perhaps: bitterly disappointing.

Comment: "That cloud looks good enough to eat."  "Looks good enough to eat" is an idiom.

Comment: I have to ask but what is *cocking*? It must be a thing, right? But a thing that looks like cake frosting, which is usually thick creamy-like icing. If *cocking* is a typo, I still can't figure out what it should be.

Comment: @Jim yes i do mean caulking. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those inanimate objects that look good to eat are only 'illusions', so far as I know; 'an illusion of edibility' or 'an appetizing illusion' would put a finer point on it, I suppose. I know of no single word for the concept you're asking about.

In the case of clouds, there are some that look like popcorn, and they're called 'popcorn clouds'.

The ["Cloud Appreciation Society"](https://cloudappreciationsociety.org/), avowed enemy of blue-sky thinking, presents a regular stew of clouds that look good to eat, as well as clouds that look like other things.

Answer (score 1):

Delectable; delicious; yummy; kosher; succulent.